# Can I use "sleep-in" as a noun like "lie-in"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, american-english

I have some questions about "sleep in".

1. Do you use the expression "to have a lie-in" in the US, Canada and other English-speaking countries?
2. Can I use "sleep-in" as a noun like "lie-in"? "Have a nice sleep-in" is correct?
3. If "sleep-in" can't be used as a noun, is there any noun in American English like "lie-in"?

Comment: "to sleep in" is common, but "to have a sleep-in" is not (perhaps you mean a "sleep over"?) I have never heard of "lie in". It would be helpful if you give better context regarding the situation you are trying to describe.

Comment: In the USA, we use *sleep in* as a verb  but not as a noun, to my knowledge.

Comment: It would help if you would explain what "lie-in" means to you. Are you talking about a long stay in bed in the morning?

Comment: @ColleenV, I'm pretty sure it's well-known BE idiom to say "I'll have a lie-in" when an American would say "I'll sleep in".

Comment: @ThePhoton It's well-known to BrE speakers, but Tracy has tagged this AmE, so those of us fluent in AmE but not BrE might need an explanation to make sure we're understanding it correctly and not just guessing.

Comment: *Lie-in* is occasionally used in AmE to refer to a protest, in the same way as *sit-in*.

Comment: "Lie-in" is very common in BrE to mean stay in bed for longer than normal. We use it as a compound noun (note the article "a"). I expect they say something else in that 'other place'.

Answer (score 3):

1. No, that is not something a US English speaker would say or understand.
2. No, not as a noun in general conversation.
3. You could say "nap",  "shut eye"  or "snooze".

"Sleep in" would always be used in the verb form.

> I'm off work so I'm going to sleep in tomorrow.

Meaning sleep late.

If you're talking about a kids overnight party, that would be a "sleep over" or "slumber party".

Comment: How can "a lie-in" be a verb. It has the indefinite article "a" and thus can only be an NP.

Comment: I would add, for 2., that the sentiment "have a nice lie-in" is pretty unusual *culturally* in the US (or at least the Midwest) by any vocabulary. It would be correct in terms of language to say "have fun sleeping in" or "enjoy your chance to sleep in" or similar, but it might come across as a criticism, since getting up early/on time is seen as a virtue. An exception would be if there is a specific context, like a long-awaited vacation or kids going off to summer camp for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite possible to use [*sleep in*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sleep+in) as a synonym of *lie in* - staying in bed in the morning.  However, the noun *sleep-in*, with a hyphen, carries a different nuance - in British English at least.

It is common to use the suffix '*-in*' on a verb to create a noun indicating that it is a communal activity.

This started with the coining of the term [*love-in*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/love-in) in the 1960s to describe hippy gatherings.
The term [*sit-in*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&q=sit-in) has been used for many years to describe a form of protest.  I have seen *lie-in* used to describe a similar form of protest.

Journalists in particular sometimes use the *-in* suffix on almost any verb.  It is used to imply a communal activity, not necessarily conventional.

Comment: In American English *sleep in* is not used as a noun.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yep... in Britain and Ireland.
2. Not commonly turned into a noun, but people will know exactly what you mean in context. Generally a phrasal verb. In Ireland and Britain that is.
3. Can't advise on American English. For sure, 'a lie in'and 'to have a lie in' are very common in Ireland... and seen as a great luxury. Wohooo... I can have a lie in tomorrow! I think we gen use 'sleep in' for over sleeping... e.g. when it makes you late. But you'll get your message across without raising too many eyebrows if you use either verb/noun and it makes sense!
   P.s. found this thread as i used "a sleep in" to Italian visitors who questioned me about it and got me thinking!